# Do lemon and yogurt remove tan when applied on the skin?

Tags: natural-remedies

http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2012-07-03/beauty/31330949_1_juice-skin-aloe-vera

> Mixing together some gram flour, lime juice and some curd on the affected area on a regular basis gives best results against tanning.

*(Note from me:) Read curd as yogurt. Indians tend to think that curd and yogurt are synonyms.*

http://www.knowabouthealth.com/6-quick-natural-tips-to-treat-sun-tanning/1524/

> Yoghurt + lemon bleach:  Mix yoghurt with lemon juice and apply it on your skin daily before bath. This is one of the best remedy for reducing sun tan.

http://naturalremediesforcure.blogspot.in/2012/12/natural-ways-to-remove-sun-tan.html

> Lemon juice is citric acid that helps remove the tan and the cucumber and rose water are cooling agents.
>
> Apply yogurt on the areas affected by sun tan. Yogurt is very effective in reducing sun tan. You can apply yogurt on your skin daily. For better results add tomato juice in yogurt. Tomato juice can be also applied alone to treat sun tan.

http://www.speedyremedies.com/tips-and-homemade-recipes-for-removing-sun-tan.html

> Prepare a face mask by mixing a tablespoon of gram flour, two teaspoons of yogurt (preferably sour) and a few drops of lime juice.
>
> Apply this paste on your face and wash it off with lukewarm water after 20 minutes. Follow this therapy two to three times in a day. In case you do not have yogurt, use raw milk.

**Is it true that lemon and yogurt have something to do with the tan removal?**
Have any studies been done on this?

Comment: I see it's a popular home bleach to use lemon though. I remember reading about using it for cleaning as well.

Comment: Does people want to get rid of their tan in India? I have no clue about cultural differences in this.

Comment: @Wertilq In India fairer girls are "always" preferred by men. Creams like these are in a huge demand in India. http://www.fairandlovely.in/index.html

Comment: @Wertilq in a colder climate a Tan was once a sign of wealth - you could afford to go abroad on holiday. In climates like India dark skin is considered unattractive in some regions / casts for the same underlying reason - if you work outdoors all day then you're likely to be more heavily tanned than someone who's lifestyle permits them to remain indoors most of the time.

Comment: @Ian ahh that makes sense. I know that in Sweden a light tan is seen as something really attractive, and especially during summer, you're SUPPOSED to have a tan. My sisters-in-law are half Indian, and their natural skin colour pretty much is exactly the level of tan swedes try to achieve.

Comment: @Ian Source for that first claim? Up until recently a tan was *always* seen as a sign of poorness, even in colder climates. Indeed, people who went abroad on holidays and cared about their reputation went to great pains to prevent tanning. After all, that’s where the word *posh* [allegedly comes from](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/posh). Tanning becoming attractive is a development of (the second half of) the 20th century.

Comment: @Kon "Tanning becoming attractive is a development of (the second half of) the 20th century". It seems that we are in agreement. I said "once", not "historically" or "up until recently". Its a cultural view that varies globally. It is no longer the 20th century and where I live a heavy tan is now often seen as quite an "essex" thing (not good). But according to Wertilq it's still popular in Sweden. It was an informal query in a comment about the differences in the cultural perception of tanning. I provided an example that he could relate to. If you're interested you could ask it as a question.

Comment: ...cont: but I imagine that it would be closed as 'Too Localized' (damn comment length >.<)